# Preview LaTeX fragment on indirect buffers

Tags: org-mode, latex, preview-latex, indirect-buffers

I am writing my research notes in `org-mode` and they contain many LaTeX formulas. I use the preview feature (`C-c C-x C-l`) a lot. As the notes are rather large, I also tend to use an indirect buffer, to jump around to have a quick glance to refer to some other part of the text.
While the indirect buffer will show the rendered formulas when I open it (assuming the original buffer was showing them), I cannot make them go doing `C-c C-c`. Conversely, if I open the indirect buffer while the original buffer is NOT showing the formulas, I cannot generate them in the indirect buffer. I get a message saying

```
user-error: Can’t preview LaTeX fragment in a non-file buffer
```

So, is there an easy way to enable org-mode to render and hide the formulas in indirect buffers?

I would not mind if doing this would mess-up (i.e. also hide, also display) the formulas in the main buffer (as long as I can re-render/display once I am back there).

For reference: GNU Emacs 25.1.2; Org-mode version 8.2.10

Answer (score 1):

I find indirect buffers to be indispensable when using org-mode. Use `clone-indirect-buffer` instead of `make-indirect-buffer` to remedy your issue. You will then be able to render and hide Latex fragments independently within each buffer.

Comment: Can someone clarify the difference between clone-indirect-buffer and make-indirect-buffer? Documentation is not making it clear for me.

Comment: I originally was using clone indirect buffer. I have this problem either way, with `make-indirect-buffer` or `clone-indirect-buffer`. @James maybe there is something else in your setup that makes it work for you? What version of emacs / org-mode do you use?